# Different Results in R and Shiny for returning data between time periods

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data set with fields timestamp, number1 , number2 ,.. etc. The sample data would look like this

1487808841,7378393242,7378373931,..... 1487808841,7378393242,7378373931,..... 1487808841,7378393245,7378373932,.....

I need to build a shiny application which takes two input start time and end time and returns the data between the range.

I converted the timestamp field using

data$TimeStamp<-as.POSIXct(data$TimeStamp,origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT") .

This is my shiny code.

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Enter the start Time and End Time',

  div( id = "eg3",
       fluidRow(
         column(width = 11, offset = 1,
                h4('Enter the start Time and End Time'),
                sliderInput("starttime", "Date & Time:", 
                            min=as.POSIXlt("2017-02-23 00:00:00", "GMT"),
                            max=as.POSIXlt("2017-02-24 23:59:59", "GMT"),
                            value=as.POSIXlt("2010-01-01 00:00:00", "GMT"),
                            timezone = "GMT"),
                sliderInput("endtime", "Date & Time:", 
                            min=as.POSIXlt("2017-02-23 00:00:00", "GMT"),
                            max=as.POSIXlt("2017-02-24 23:59:59", "GMT"),
                            value=as.POSIXlt("2010-01-01 00:00:00", "GMT"),
                            timezone = "GMT"),
                dataTableOutput("output_slider2")
         )
       )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$output_slider2  <- renderDataTable({
    filtered<-cdr1[cdr1$TimeStamp>=input$starttime & cdr1$TimeStamp<=input$endtime,]
    filtered[,1]<-as.character(filtered[,1])
    datatable(filtered)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Now when I enter start date and time as 2017-02-23 01:00:00 and end date as 2017-02-23 18:00:00 it retrieves 45,301 rows where as

```
data[data$TimeStamp>="2017-02-23 01:00:00" & data$TimeStamp<="2017-02-23 18:00:00",]
```

retrieves 32,400 records .

Why Shiny is retrieving more records ?

How to solve it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `as.POSIXct()` is not same as `as.POSIXlt()`. Stay consistent with both modes.

Comment: Parfit , I tried that .. but still same result

Comment: Well, your guess is as good as ours! From our point of view we can't see how or where your data derives. Run `nrow()`, `ncol()`, `str()`, `summary()` before filtering on both sides and see if they match.